# How to use Google Action Builder with my own server

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to develop an action to google assistant. So i red the documentation here https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview and i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1hxvniJ18s

It s worked and i was allow to develop and test my app in the simulator. The problem is that when it's come to webhook i don't totaly understand how it's work. On the webhook icon i got this [image: Webhook interface]

The seconde one allow me to use Google cloud function and firebase but i had to add my billing account to make it available. I also get a console where i can code my fonctions and my responses.

And if i am correct, the first one allow me to connect to my own Api. But i can only enter one field that is the URL adresse and nothing else so how do i code it? Also i see everywhere people using node.js and i would like to use php is it possible?

To sum up my problem, i would like to know how i could connect my action builder to an other service(Api) than google ones? If it's possible to run my server in php and how do i interact with my google action?(I think it's by sending json back and forth but i'am not sure how to do it?) Finally i would like to know if it's possible to test it in local server with mamp and phpmyadmin for exemple to test the answer of the server?

I would be very grateful if someone could help me, show me how to set up all this.

Answer (score 0):

> But i can only enter one field that is the URL adresse and nothing else so how do i code it?

When you develop your webhook, you will need to have a single publicly accessible endpoint to connect with. This endpoint will receive an HTTP POST request and you will need to respond with an appropriate response.

> Also i see everywhere people using node.js and i would like to use php is it possible?

Any language that can run on a web server can work. Node.js is one that is used a lot, but PHP can work just as well. You can create an `actions.php` file and then enter an endpoint address *https://example.com/actions.php* that will be called. You may need to refer to the [Request and Response reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/fulfill) for the expected format.

> if it's possible to test it in local server with mamp and phpmyadmin for exemple to test the answer of the server?

It's somewhat possible. You'll need to have some method of sending mock requests to your local server, which might be as easy as using cURL or other tools [like Postman](https://www.postman.com/product/rest-client/).

Unfortunately my personal experience with PHP tools is limited, so I can't necessarily walk-through the specifics. But it does seem like you know these tools a bit more and should be familiar enough to be able to get started.